# Extracting attachments from mail box using AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I need to extract the attachments(pdf and .xlsx) from mail box using auto hot key.

Can somebody elaborate the steps for achieving this?

Any links could also be of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@dheerendra

First, figure out how to do it in a stepwise fashion with just the mouse and/or keyboard (look for shortcut keys or accelerator keys or hot keys - those things with underlines under them). Once you can do it manually, secondly, use AutoHotKey (or any other scripting utility) to automate those steps. These links can help.

AutoHotKey can replicate Mouse clicks at locations:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm

AutoHotKey can replicate sending Keys from the keyboard:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

That should do it, now you just put the steps into the script, maybe with some wait times between steps, or maybe with some error checking, or maybe add some flow control logic, or perhaps get and respond to additional user input, or even a GUI.

But if you have any trouble, show us what you tried (just enough of your code to disclose the troublesome part), and tell us what you expected to happen, and then tell us what actually happened.

**EDIT**: (Examples of the improvements)
E.g., you could use control logic to save in a place and name it depending on the sender or subject, or a category:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm

Or you could get simple user input to determine where to save it and what to call it:
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm

Or even create a full blown application with a GUI and connections to other data, and use that to establish a complete workflow process.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm

Also, you didn't say what Mail client you are using, but I should mention that in addition to scripting mouse and keyboard actions, AutoHotKey lets you easily interact with Microsoft Outlook com interface which can easily expose email message objects and their attachments.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ComObjCreate.htm

Good luck, and Hth,